Click event function executes one more time
I have grid of similar cards with buttons. Every button has click event for launching modal window. When modal window has dissapeared, some logic performs. But an issue appears: when modal window appears and hides for second time, hiding function performs two times. When modal window appears and hides for third time, hiding function performs three times and etc. Why is this happening?


const detailBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('card__detail');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

for(let i = 0; i < detailBtns.length; i++) {
    const parent = detailBtns[i].parentNode;

    detailBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        windowLaunch();
    });
}

function windowLaunch() {
    modal.classList.add('open');


    const hideModalBtn = modal.getElementsByClassName('modal__hide');
    hideModalBtn[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
        modal.classList.remove('open');

    });
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card"><button class="card__detail">Add</button></div>
  <div class="card"><button class="card__detail">Add</button></div>
  <div class="card"><button class="card__detail">Add</button></div>
  <div class="card"><button class="card__detail">Add</button></div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
        <button class="modal__add">Add to basket</button>
      <div class="modal__hide"></div>
</div>




Every time you call windowLaunch, another event listener is added for the click to an existing element. Because you are using anonymous functions, javascript considers each of them unique and will execute them one by one. Either turn it into a scoped function so you can reuse it (JS wont add the same method twice), or remove the event listener again before adding it (which also requires you to store it really).

You can move the const hideModalBtn and hideModalBtn[0].addEventListener("click" outside the function becouse is just one modal. No need to execute that script each time you run windowLaunch
